# Enable SSL for whole Drupal 8 site

Tags: 8, feeds, ssl

I'm running a Drupal 8 site behind a nginx webserver. All http request are redirected to https. My problem is that rss links on that site are http links only.

With Drupal 7 by setting the base_url all links are shown as https links. In Drupal 8 this option is missing. How can I set the whole site to https? Is there a config option for setttings.php?

Comment: What rss links exactly, how do you create them? if you access Drupal over https, everything should use https, unless it is render cached as http or is somehow hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the RSS links are rendered, I would suggest calling them over with a protocol-relative URL such as:

```
//domain.com/rss-feed....
```

This will force the information to be sent over based on the way the page was rendered.  If the page was rendered using https:// it will use https:// in place of '//'

Answer (score -1):

To Enable SSL Certificate on Drupal, Write the following line of code in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect to HTTPS

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: As I stated in my post: I use nginx and have already enabled https redirection (and .htaccess files don't work with nginx). So that's not the problem I want to solve...